# Extract values from cells and add in different columns

Tags: excel, vba

How do I split and extract values from a cell with semi-colon and line break line into multiple columns.

I checked online, seems several come close but do not fit what I need.

I have a worksheet, called "Orders", and only column A filled with concatenated order details (refer to the sample image link, column A)

I tried to use the below piece of code. The text split with multiple columns but with the full text for each and not the desired value + entries did not have a 'Coupon' line:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Dim i as Long
i = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set orderDetails = ws.Range("A1:A" & i)
        
For Each cell In orderDetails
    cell = Replace(cell, vbLf, "")
Next

orderDetails.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True
```

The desired output:
[image: Final Output]

UPDATE: Added column A cell values

```
Sub-Total - USD 171.43; VAT - USD 8.57; Shipping - USD 0.00; Total - USD 180.00
Sub-Total - USD 171.43; VAT - USD 8.57; Shipping - USD 0.00; Total - USD 180.00
Sub-Total - USD 471.43; VAT - USD 23.57; Shipping - USD 0.00; Coupon (WELCOME) - USD -70.71; Total - USD 424.28
Sub-Total - USD 371.43; VAT - USD 18.57; Shipping - USD 0.00; Coupon (WELCOME) - USD -70.71; Total - USD 319.29
```

Comment: You need to research the VBA split method which is designed for this type of problem.

Comment: Do the column headers exactly match the text in the column A entries? I would suggest using `Split`.

Comment: @SJR, not exactly.  For example the coupon line. I need two columns for it. The coupon name and the coupon value

Comment: Do the others match? For coupon, do they always follow the same layout name-USD-value? Could any of them be missing in any row?

Comment: They all follow the format: name-USD-value. Just the coupon is different: there's the name of the coupon () and it appears in the cell if its applied or not (like in A1 and A2 compared to A3 and A4)